# How to iterate an array of a dynamic size in a loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, dynamic, for-loop

I am using VB.NET.

I would like have an array called A1 and I will perform for loop inside that array.

1. In the middle of the for loop, I need to remove an item from that A1 array.
2. I am aware that if I remove that object from A1 array, the program will crash (out of bounds error message).

Which array variable in VB.NET would allow me to perform the task above?

Code sample is most welcomed!

Thank you.

Comment: please show the code you are trying to use (removing something from an array should not cause an out of bound error, resizing it would)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a list instead of an array (or convert the array you have to a `List(of T)`.
The trick then is to move from the end of the list to the front instead of the other way around.
For example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim RndGenerator as New Random
    Dim a As New List(Of Double)
    For i = 0 To 99
        a.Add(RndGenerator.NextDouble() * 10) 'Populate the list
    Next
    For i = a.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1  'This loop performs the deletion.
        If a(i) > 5 Then a.RemoveAt(i)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey() 'Or debugger.Break to look at the result
End Sub
```

This will populate a list with random numbers from 0 to 10. It then removes all numbers >5 from the list.

## Edit:

Good point from Steven Doggart on not using VB6 Relics. Edited the code to use the System.Random class instead.

Comment: This is a good example, but I would be remiss if I did not mention that it would be better to use the `Random` class rather than the older VB6 style `Randomize` and `Rnd` methods.  Also, it's worth mentioning that another solution, though slightly less efficient, is to convert the list to an array and then loop through the array.  Then you can alter the list as much as you want without affecting your loops iterator (e.g. `For Each i As Double In a.ToArray()`).  +1 though for a good answer :)